# Azure Data Factory Connect to OpenVPN

Tags: azure, ip, azure-data-factory, openvpn

I am trying to connect to an Aurora Database in AWS that can only be access through an OpenVPN IP address. Our reporting server is set up in Azure, and I would like to move some of the data from the Aurora Database in AWS to the reporting server in Azure. I haven't had any issues with connecting to AWS sources in ADF before, but have never had to use ADF to connect to a specific IP like this.

Is this possible in ADF? Or possible leveraging other Azure resources?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- Transit VNET within Azure
- Self-Hosted Integration Runtime deployed to VM within this VNET
- Virtual Appliance within same VNET that is the OpenVPN client
- VNet Peering between Data Factory VNet and Transit VNet
- Data Factory pipeline using Integration Runtime to get data and push to Azure storage.